# How to change currency on country change in shipping form in the checkout page magento 2.3

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.4, currency, country-regions, checkout-summary

I want to update my checkout cart summary when the user selects the country from shipping address, cart price and currency change according to the country he selected in the shipping address.

How can I do this in Magento 2.3?

Comment: Hello! Did you get any solution regarding this? Because I have also the same requirement.